# Donald Knuth Dancing Links Implementation Clarification

Tags: structure

I'm currently in the process of implementing a Dancing Links data structure.
However, there is one thing I am unsure about.

Nodes obviously have UP, DOWN, LEFT & RIGHT pointers.
Am I right in assuming that the UP & DOWN pointers of each node regardless of the row they are on point to the column header? Or do they point to the node above/below them?

I can't seem to find any material which clarifies which is correct.

Thanks

Comment: For material, I think the best reference is Knuth's original paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047v1.pdf. On page 6 you'll see an example matrix with all links drawn explicitly. Indeed, these UP and DOWN pointers are the only way to traverse the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that they point to the entries above and below them. That way, when you remove a row from the matrix in the deterministic step, you can splice that row back in efficiently by using the dancing links technique. If they just pointed at the column header, after removing the row, you couldn't easily add it back.

Comment: This answer is correct (I have implemented dancing links a couple of times).

Comment: They need to point to up/down neighbor cells because these are the remaining solution rows for that column, where a column is one of the constraints. You'll notice many implementations do track the header cell for each column though, but you can find the column header by iterating up until you reach the header (which implies there's some attribute, a name or a type, that you can use to determine a cell is a header node)